# how to display certain properties in objects, as above? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const books = [
            {
                "name": "John Adventure",
                "year": 2021,
                "author": "John doe",
            },
            {
                "name": "Marry Adventure",
                "year": 2021,
                "author": "Marry doe",
            },
            {
                "name": "Steven Adventure",
                "year": 2021,
                "author": "Steven doe",
            }
        ];
```

result

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "books": [
            {
                "name": "John Adventure",
            },
            {
                "name": "Marry Adventure",
            },
            {
                "name": "Steven Adventure",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

how to display certain properties in objects, as above? javascript,
how to show only name property object in array like that
helppp

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `map` operator to iterate each element from `books` array

```js
const books = [
            {
                "name": "John Adventure",
                "year": 2021,
                "author": "John doe",
            },
            {
                "name": "Marry Adventure",
                "year": 2021,
                "author": "Marry doe",
            },
            {
                "name": "Steven Adventure",
                "year": 2021,
                "author": "Steven doe",
            }
        ];
        
let result = {
  status: "success",
  data: {}
};
result.data.books =  books.map(item => { return {"name":item.name}}); 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "books": books.map( book => ({"name": book.name)) )
    }
}
```

the variable `data` would contain the object you wanted

Comment: books.map(book => ({"name": book.name}), thankss sir